# Solve $ y'=y^2e^{-x}+4y+2e^x $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Not a bernouli equation because the y^2 cannot be factored from right hand side. Any ideas on how to approach such an equation ? [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3D%28y%5E2%29%28e%5E%28-x%29%29%2B4y%2B2e%5Ex) gives a nice answer

Comment: Do you have an initial condition?

Comment: no, it asks to solve for y explicitly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y'=(ye^{-x/2}+2e^{x/2})^2-2e^x=e^{-x}(y+2e^x)^2-2e^{x}$$
Let 
$$t=y+2e^{x} \Rightarrow \frac{dt}{dx}=y'+2e^x \Rightarrow y'=\frac{dt}{dx}-2e^{x}$$
Hence,
$$\frac{dt}{dx}-2e^x=e^{-x}t^2-2e^x \Rightarrow \frac{dt}{dx}=e^{-x}t^2$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{t}=e^{-x}+C \Rightarrow \frac{1}{y+2e^x}=e^{-x}+C$$
$$\Rightarrow y=\frac{1}{C+e^{-x}}-2e^x$$

Comment: your method looks simple and nice ! thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Substitute $y=ve^{x}$ to get a separable equation for $v$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints;

Let $$y=e^x v(x), \; \; y'=v e^x+v' e^x$$

Then the DE becomes $$v'=v^2+3v+2$$

Let $$v=-\frac{u'}{u}, \;\; v'=\frac{u'^2}{u^2}-\frac{u''}{u}$$

Then you have $$u''-3u'+2u=0$$ which is where I'll leave it to you.

Comment: Are you sure is not $u'' -3u'+2u = 0$?